# Help with HAML: Mixing text and other HTML tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am converting my ERB template to a HAML template.

```
<p>
   Welcome to <span><%= name1 %> </span>, <span> <%= name2 %></span> and <span><%= name3 %></span>.
</p>
```

This is what I have come up with

```
%p
  Welcome to 
  %span= name1
  ,
  %span= name2
  and
  %span= name3
  .
```

I have a feeling that there is much more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no reason you shouldn't use inline HTML tags in your Haml document. See [this post](http://chriseppstein.github.com/blog/2010/02/08/haml-sucks-for-content) explaining why Haml isn't good for inline markup.

```
<p>
   Welcome to <span>#{name1}</span>, <span>#{name2}</span> and <span>#{name3}</span>.
</p>
```

Comment: The `<p>` tag can still be a Haml `%p`, can't it?

Comment: I was aware of HAML's ability to embed HTML. I needed validation for this approach. The article that you linked is quite good. Still mixing two Ruby embedding syntax is yucky.